# TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplates Needing Headers

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a treeview that can be simplified down to:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding A}">
    <TreeView.Resources>

        <HierarchialDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:A}">
            <!-- XAML to display objects of type A -->
        </HierarchialDataTemplate>

        <HierarchialDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:B}">
            <!-- XAML to display objects of type B -->
        </HierarchialDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:C}">
            <!-- XAML to display objects of type C -->
        </DataTemplate>

    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

And it works well.

Now, I have a seemingly simple requirement to add headers to the DataTemplates such as:

[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this, as I can only edit the style of each individual item from with the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, I can't alter the template itself to display static headers (shown in bold above).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am just god awful at WPF.

Comment: Instead of TreeView, you can look to achieve the functionality with `DataGrid` and `RowDetailsTemplate` of it.

Comment: I think you want to set the [`ItemsPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve this with a `TreeView` is to re-template the `TreeViewItem`. The following is a fairly minimal example, you will almost certainly want to up the pretties.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ToggleButton
                                Name="ExpandButton"
                                ClickMode="Press"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                />
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                ContentSource="Header"
                                />
                            <TextBlock
                                Name="Caption"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Text="List Caption"
                                />
                            <ItemsPresenter
                                Name="Content"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="2"
                                />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Caption" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                <Setter TargetName="Content" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="ExpandButton" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Note: Templating `TreeViewItem` like this will only add the caption to the child items. If you want root items to also have captions then you can either re-template the `TreeView` in a similar way or just put something above the `TreeView` itself.